# Same padding on the sides with media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I resize the browser window to under 768 px the boxes is getting different padding on the sides of my column boxes: [See the example here](https://www.bootply.com/render/2LQQLJ0CAZ).

I tried to set a media query with something like this, but I am aware of that it is not the correct way to do it at all:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .small-padding-left {
            padding-left: 7.5px;
        }

    .col-sm-8 {
        padding-right: 7.5px;
    }

}
```

[image: Example picture]

Does anybody knows a good way how I can achieve this? This is my code so far:

```
/* Global CSS*/
    .row > div{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .content{
        background: #b4bac0;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    /* When there is 2 columns on top of eachother */
    .sidebar{
        background: #b4bac0;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    .sidebar-top{
        min-height: 140px;
        background: #dbdfe7;
    }
    .sidebar-bottom{
        min-height: 145px;
        background: #7e8aa0;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
    /* Padding used for the core CSS */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:5px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:7.5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:7.5px;
    }
    /* Media quries */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .small-padding-left {
                padding-left: 7.5px;
            }

        .col-sm-8 {
            padding-right: 7.5px;
        }

    }

<body style="background-color: #4940fb;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 small-padding right">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 small-padding left">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7 small-padding right">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding left">
                        <div class="sidebar-top"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding left">
                        <div class="sidebar-bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: Hello. The version is 3.3.7

Comment: You are using bootstrap 4.0.0. ! I checked in the website

Comment: Bootply are just a place to post code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some custom css to make it work the right way. Try adding this code to your css file.

```
.row {
  margin-left: -7.5px;
  margin-right: -7.5px;
}

.row>[class*="col-"] {
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  padding-right: 7.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example  the issue happens in below 575 width.

please update the media query in your css file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
.small-padding.right
{
padding-right: 15px;
}
.small-padding.left
{
padding-left: 15px;

}
}
```